# BouncyCastle Encoding differences

Tags: java, c#, encoding, x509certificate, bouncycastle

I'm trying to calculate the hash of a public key to match what ApplePay is giving me.  I can't get BouncyCastle in C# to give me the public key in the right format so I can hash it.  However the Java version that I'm porting works just fine.  OpenSSL also gives the right response, but I'd prefer not to have to deal with OpenSSL as well as BC to do this.

Java: (works)

```
ECPublicKey key = (ECPublicKey) certificate.getPublicKey();
byte[] keyBytes = key.getEncoded(); 

MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA256", PROVIDER_NAME);
byte[] keyHash = messageDigest.digest(keyBytes);    

String base64keyBytes = new String(Base64.encode(keyBytes));
//base64keyBytes == MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAE+4wQWWRnPqGlsncZX17t0CfLOl6u
// 68aXUsqnzlIcpCdDukHhxibd2MjHPFGpnK3ZKdHxIFh+NBQvGssM5ncm1g==
// line break added for readability
```

OpenSSL: (works)

```
openssl x509 -noout -pubkey -in <file> -inform der 
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAE+4wQWWRnPqGlsncZX17t0CfLOl6u
68aXUsqnzlIcpCdDukHhxibd2MjHPFGpnK3ZKdHxIFh+NBQvGssM5ncm1g==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

C#: (keyBytes are wrong)

```
SubjectPublicKeyInfo pubinfo = SubjectPublicKeyInfoFactory.CreateSubjectPublicKeyInfo(certificate.GetPublicKey());
byte[] keyBytes = pubinfo.GetEncoded();

byte[] keyHash = DigestUtilities.CalculateDigest("SHA_256", keyBytes);

string keyBytesEncoded = Convert.ToBase64String(keyBytes);
/*keyBytesEncoded == MIIBKjCB4wYHKoZIzj0CATCB1wIBATAsBgcqhkjOPQEBAiEA/////wAAAAEAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAD///////////////8wWwQg/////wAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD/
//////////////wEIFrGNdiqOpPns+u9VXaYhrxlHQawzFOw9jvOPD4n0mBLAx
UAxJ02CIbnBJNqZnjhE50mt4GffpAEIQNrF9Hy4SxCR/i85uVjpEDydwN9gS3r
M6D0oTlF2JjClgIhAP////8AAAAA//////////+85vqtpxeehPO5ysL8YyVRAg
EBA0IABPuMEFlkZz6hpbJ3GV9e7dAnyzperuvGl1LKp85SHKQnQ7pB4cYm3djI
xzxRqZyt2SnR8SBYfjQULxrLDOZ3JtY=
line break added for readability */
```

What is the right way to port the GetEncoding?

I know it's the key data that wrong because when I manually force in the data from openssl I get the right hash.

EDIT: Added the out puts.

Comment: Could you also show the output of the calls to Java and C# `GetEncoded` (in base 64 or hexadecimals)?

Comment: Added the respective outputs.

Comment: I must call foul on this one. There is no way that the base64-encoded output of Java's MessageDigest.digest() method looks like you described. Please post the correct code/output, which may very well be simply the base64 encoding of the `getEncoded()` outputs, and these are not hashes at all.

Comment: The data I posted encoded if of the input to the hash, not the hash it self.   As stated in my question the hash works fine, the problem is getEncoded() does not behave the same in c# as it does in Java.

The data the comes out of getEncoded is functionally the same as far as i can tell, I can rebuild the key object from the byte[], but because it's not the same byte array the hash is coming out wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would just be:

```
byte[] keyBytes = certificate.CertificateStructure.SubjectPublicKeyInfo.GetDerEncoded()
```

Comment: Wow thank you!!  I was just getting ready to pull down the java source code and see what it did differently from C#.